# Column alignment using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a grid using bootstrap. Below is the code I am using:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">Services</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Name</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Organization</div>
</div>
```

So, I want Name and Organization in same row as two different columns. But, for some reason, it's stacking all the columns vertically. I used example from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options for reference.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I want my result to look like below:

> Services
>      Name ---------------- Organization

Dotted line is just working as a tab here to represent separation between columns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that in bootstrap, the sum of each row, in you class tag is 12 to complete all the page.

So where do you want to have two separate columns ? If you want it for all screens  you need to assign the **col-xs-6** to each column, because 12/6 =2 and for greater screen, same rules Will be applied.

Another example, if you want stacked column for mobile, 2-3 of the page for tablet and all the page for greater screebs, you'll need to override your class tag like this :

"Col-xs-12 col-++-4 col-md-6" (don't remember what is at place of the ++ ^^)

Comment: Thank you for your response Nicolas. I tried your answer by making sum of my columns to 12 by assigning col-xs-6 to each column, but it's still same result with columns stacked vertically.

Comment: Ok, so explain me which result do you want, try to schematize it please ^^

Comment: Have you send me your expectation ? Because i don't see it (in the comment section)

Comment: I just edited my question to show, how I want my result to look like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want this ?

```
  <div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-12">Services</div> 
</div> 
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">Name</div> 
<div class="col-md-6">Organization</div>
 </div>
```

Edit : if i understand, you want a separation between name and organisation, so maybe try something like this

```
 <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12">Services</div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">Name</div> 
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Organization</div>
         </div>
```

I think there is a way to have the same result without this empty div, but don't really remember

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap everything is based on the 12 (like clocks). This is so that your layout can have the maximum number of symmetrical divisions. Each div with the prefix "col-" is basically specifying how many blocks (of the twelve you have per row) you want that div to take up. So your code is saying:

Row 1: One div 8 blocks wide *+ 4 blocks of space*

Row 2: One div 4 blocks wide + One div 3 blocks wide *+ 5 blocks of space*

So they *should* be appearing as you are expecting (though not taking up the full width of the screen).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">Services</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Name</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Organization</div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle with it working > [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/zdnq14e6/1/)

I'd suggest there were a couple of possible reasons it's not working as you'd expect:

1. Your CSS file 'bootstrap.css' is not referenced correctly
2. You are viewing it on a screen that is lower width than the Bootstrap's "medium width" which, iirc, is 960px so it is collapsing "small width"

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I was using Kendo and Bootstrap together because of which libraries were conflicting. Updating the libraries solved the issue.
Thanks all for your responses!